# CSS Selector not recognizing numbers

Tags: python, css, webdriver

I am working on webdriver using python. I am getting error for following css selector

```
65535-123 > td:nth-of-type(9) > a
```

I read "In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and ISO 10646 characters U+00A1 and higher, plus the hyphen (`-`) and the underscore (`_`); they cannot start with a digit, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item).code "

So I tried following:

```
\65535\-123 > td:nth-of-type(9) > span
```

But it didnt work. Can you please let me know the correct way to proceed? Should I got for xpath in this scenario?

Comment: Even the HTML spec says element ID's must not start with a digit. So it's invalid HTML. I'd hazard a guess even selecting using jQuery wouldn't work either. You need to fix the underlying issue, it's invalid HTML so you cannot guarantee what the various frameworks are *actually* going to do with and you cannot guarantee what the browser will do with it.

Comment: What is 65535-123? An id/name or something else? Can you post brief sample html?

Answer (score 0):

I'm feeling you are missing class or id selector so use like this

`#\65535-123 > td:nth-of-type(9) > span`

But it's not good idea to have like this. place some characters like this

```
#abc65535-123 > td:nth-of-type(9) > span
```

Comment: '65535-123' is an id and I cant change.

Comment: So you need to use `#` before the id. like this `#65535-123`. BTW: an id should not begin with a number. read the CSS spec..

Comment: Yes I used #65535-123 and tried #\65535-123. Its old code and I need to automate the code using selenium webdriver. Hence i cant change the id

Comment: I am placing html code. Please suggest if any.                   <div id="One" class="auto" style="height: 350px; width: 760px;">
<table id="tblOne">
<thead>
<tbody id="tbodyOne">
<tr id="65535-123" class="hilite">
<a class="LinkDetail" href="/settings/ONE?tableid=0&tableidExt=ONETWO" tabindex="23"/>
</td>
</tr>